# Probability of Brownian Motion touching a circle

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Currently, I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09744) about planar Brownian Motion. However, I am just getting to know Brownian Motion so I am not familiar with all well-known properties of BM or stochastic processes.

I am looking at a Brownian Motion that is somewhere in a neighborhood of several circles $\partial B_{r_i}(z_0), z_0\in\mathbb R^2, \ i=1,\dots,n,$ such that $r_1<\dots<r_n.$ The author says that when $BM$ starts on a circle $\partial B_{r_i},$ the probability BM hits $\partial B_{r_{i+1}}$ before $\partial B_{r_{i-1}}$ is $\frac 1 2$.

Although this seems like quite a simple statement, I don't really why this is. My intuition says that if the distances i.e. the $r_i$ were the same, then this statement is clear. However, the $r_i$ don't necessarily have to be equal.

If you could point out a few arguments for this, I'd be really glad. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** Upon request; the values are given as $r_i = R (\frac{\epsilon}{R})^\frac{i}{K}$ where $R\in(0, \frac 1 2)$, $K \geq 1$ and $i = 0,1,\dots,K.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0<y<|z|<w<\infty$ with $z\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and $z_0=0$. Using the fact that $u(x)=\ln|x|$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$ and Ito's lemma, one can show that
$$
N_t:=u\!\left(B_{t\wedge T_y}\right)-u(z)=\sum_{i=1}^2\int_0^t\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} u(B_{s\wedge T_y})\,d B_{s\wedge T_y}^i,
$$
where $T_r:=\inf\{t\ge 0:|B_t|=r\}$, is a local martingale null at 0. Stopping $N_t$ at $T_w$, one gets a uniformly integrable martingale null at 0 which converges in $L_1$. Therefore,
$$
u(z)=\mathsf{E}^z[u(B_{T_y\wedge T_w})]=\mathsf{P}^z(T_y<T_w)\ln y+\mathsf{P}^z(T_y\ge T_w)\ln w,
$$
and so, when $B_t$ starts at $z$,
$$
\mathsf{P}^z(T_y<T_w)=\frac{\ln w-\ln|z|}{\ln w-\ln y}.
$$

---

In your case, $r_i=R(\varepsilon/R)^{i/K}$ for $R\in(0,1/2)$ and some $K\in\mathbb{N}$ (see Equation (5) on page 2). So
$$
\frac{\ln r_{i+1}-\ln r_i}{\ln r_{i+1}-\ln r_{i-1}}=\frac{1}{2},
$$
as required.

Comment: Shouldn't the $\nabla$ be a $\Delta$ in your first equation ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient

Comment: I'm familiar with both the gradient and and the Laplace operator, however I found a version of your first equation in a book where the Laplace operator is used instead of your gradient. I thought the Laplace operator makes more sense because then we can use the fact that $u$ is harmonic thus $\Delta u \equiv 0$.

Comment: $\Delta u=0$ and so the second order term in Ito's lemma is zero.